# How to parallelize a program that need 0.005 seconds to terminate sequentially?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

for a project i need to parallelize a sudoku solver, that sequentially terminate in avarage in 0.005 seconds. For test i also count how many "computations" the program does to solve the sudoku, and the problem is that when i run it in multithreading, if i do a lot less "computations" of the sequential version, then the completion time of the program in multithreading is less than the sequential version, but if the sequential version does for instance 2000 computations to solve the sudoku, and the multithreading version with 2 threads does the same 2000 computations in total (so in theory 1000 per thread, and the time should be less than the sequential versione) the time is not less than the sequential version, because probably the managing and the synchronization between the two threads is heavier than the 1000 computations each (if the total program sequentially need 0.005 seconds to start and terminate, the 1000 computations would need very few time to complete).
Now the question is, i must parallelize it, and i must to it only using c++ standard library, how can i do it in that way that at least for a fixed number of threads( i dont expect that it works even with 64-128 threads), the multithreading version is always faster (less completion time) of the sequential version?

For the moment the program is based on a tree structure where each node is a possible solution, and a queue to make a task pool where each thread get a work, compute, and if it is not a solution, push back the results it has found and go on taking another work from the queue.
The code is the following:
(you can compile it with -pthread and you can run it with ./prog num_of_threads 0 0 0, where the last three zeros are not important for now).

!The only relevant code is the last part, getWork(), pushWork(), SolveSudoku(), InfiniteLoop(), the other function is just to make the example runnable but are not useful to analyze.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <math.h>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>

#define UNASSIGNED 0
#define N 9
#define ERROR_PAIR std::make_pair(-1, -1)

using namespace std;

atomic<bool> solutionFound{false};
mutex mtx;
atomic<int> worksDone{0};


//Each node has a sudoku grid and some sub-trees
struct Node {
    array<unsigned  char, N*N> grid;
    vector<Node *> child;
};


Node *newNode(const array<unsigned  char, N*N> &newGrid) {
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->grid = newGrid;
    return temp;
}

list<vector<Node *>> queueWork(0, vector<Node *>(0));

void printGrid(const array<unsigned  char, N*N> &grid) {
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        if (row == 3 || row == 6) {
            cout << "---------------------" << endl;
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            if (col == 3 || col == 6) {
                cout << "| ";
            }
            cout << (int)grid[row+col*N] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//Check if a number can be inserted in a given position
bool canInsert(const int &val, const int &row_, const int &col_,
               const array<unsigned  char, N*N> &grid) {
    //Check column
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        if (grid[row+col_*N] == val) return false;
    }
    //Check row
    for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
        if (grid[row_+col*N] == val) return false;
    }
    //Check box 3x3
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            if (row / 3 == row_ / 3 &&
                col / 3 == col_ / 3) { 
                if ((grid[row+col*N] == val)) return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//Generate a matrix randomly with n initial values
void generateMatrix(const int &seed, const int &n, array<unsigned  char, N*N> &grid) {
    srand(seed);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        int row = rand() % 9;
        int col = rand() % 9;
        int val = rand() % 9 + 1;
        if (grid[row+col*N] == UNASSIGNED && canInsert(val, row, col, grid)) {
            grid[row+col*N] = val;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

//Check if the sudoku is solved
bool isSolution(const array<unsigned char, N*N> &grid)  {
    char row_[N][N+1] = {0};
    char column_[N][N+1] = {0};
    char box[3][3][N+1] = {0};
    
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++) {
            //Mark the element in row column and box
            row_[row][grid[row+col*N]] += 1;
            column_[col][grid[row+col*N]] += 1;
            box[row / 3][col / 3][grid[row+col*N]] += 1;
            //If an element is already present
            if (box[row / 3][col / 3][grid[row+col*N]] > 1 ||
                column_[col][grid[row+col*N]] > 1 ||
                row_[row][grid[row+col*N]] > 1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//Find the first empty cell
pair<int, int> findCell(const array<unsigned  char, N*N> &grid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (grid[i+j*N] == UNASSIGNED) {
                return make_pair(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return ERROR_PAIR;
}

//Find all possible numbers that can be inserted, and update the grid with that solution. Return the set of all
//the grids, one for each possible choice.
vector<array<unsigned char, N*N>> getChoices(const int &row, const int &col, const array<unsigned  char, N*N> &grid) {
    vector<array<unsigned char, N*N>> choices;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (canInsert(i, row, col, grid)) {
            array<unsigned char, N*N> tmpGrid = grid;
            tmpGrid[row+col*N] = i;
            choices.push_back(move(tmpGrid));
        }
    }
    return choices;
}

//Update the childreen of a node.
void addChoices(vector<array<unsigned char, N*N>> &choices, Node &node) {
    while (!choices.empty()) {
        node.child.push_back(newNode(choices.back()));
        choices.pop_back();
    }
    return;
}

//Get a work from the queue
vector<Node *> getWork(const int chunkSize) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lck(mtx);
    
    if(queueWork.empty()){
        vector<Node *> error;
        return error;
    }
    if(queueWork.size()>=chunkSize){
        vector<Node *> result;
        for(int i=0; i<chunkSize;i++){
            auto tmp = queueWork.back();
            queueWork.pop_back();
        for(int i=0;i<tmp.size();i++){
            result.push_back(tmp[i]);
            }
        }
    return result;
    }

    auto tmp = queueWork.back();
    queueWork.pop_back();
    return tmp;
}

//Put a work in the queue
void pushWork(vector<Node *> &work) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lck(mtx);
    queueWork.push_back(work);
    return;
}


//Compute one step of computation for each node in input, and put all the childreen in the task vector.
void solveSudoku(vector<Node *> &nodes) {
    for (Node *&n : nodes) {
        if (findCell(n->grid) != ERROR_PAIR) {
            pair<int, int> freeCell = findCell(n->grid);
            vector<array<unsigned char, N*N>> choices = getChoices(freeCell.first, freeCell.second, n->grid);
            if (choices.empty()) { 
                delete n;
                continue; 
                }
            addChoices(choices, *n);
            vector<Node *> result;
            for (auto &n : n->child) {
                result.push_back(n);
            }
            pushWork(result);
            delete n;
            continue;
        } else if (isSolution(n->grid) && !solutionFound) {
                solutionFound.store(true);
                printGrid(n->grid);
                cout << "That's the first solution found !" << endl;

                return;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
   }
}

void infiniteLoop(const int chunkSize){
    while(!solutionFound){
        if(!queueWork.empty()){
            auto part = getWork(chunkSize);
             
            if(!part.empty()) {
                solveSudoku(part);
            } 
            worksDone++;    
        }
    } 
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 4) {
        std::cerr << "use: " << argv[0]  << " nw seed initial_values " << endl;
        return (-1);
    }

    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    const int nw = atoi(argv[1]); //Number of worker
    const int seed = atoi(argv[2]); //Seed for matrix generator
    const int initialValues = atoi(argv[3]); //Number of values to generate at the beginning
    const int chunkSize = 1;

    array<unsigned char, N*N> grid = {0}; 
    vector<thread> tids;

    if(seed != 0 && initialValues != 0){ 
        generateMatrix(seed,initialValues,grid);
    } else {
        grid = 
                                      {9, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
                                       0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 
                                       0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       5, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 0, 
                                       0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 
                                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       0, 0, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7};
    }
    
    Node *root = newNode(grid);
    vector<Node *> primoLavoro ;
    primoLavoro.push_back(root);
    solveSudoku(primoLavoro);
    

        for(int i=0;i<nw;i++){
            tids.push_back(thread(infiniteLoop,chunkSize));
        }

    cout << "tids.size()" << tids.size() << endl;
        for(thread &t : tids){
            t.join();  
        }
    


   if(!solutionFound) cout << "No solution found ! " << endl;
   
   
   chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
   chrono::duration<double> time_span2 = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

   cout << "WorksDone = " << worksDone / nw << endl;
   cout << "Tempo vecchio " << time_span2.count() << " seconds with " << nw << " threads !" << endl;
   return(0);
    
}
    
}
```

Comment: you cannot ensure that a multithreaded version is *always* faster than the sequential one. Not possible, unless you can increase the workload

Comment: you are right, i would just need that the multithreaded version is faster in average. I can increase the chunksize, so the amount of "works" that each thread does, so i can set that when i have 2 threads each of them take 2 works per time, and when i have 4 threads each thread take 4 "works" per time, will it be useful? (i think you are refering to gustaffson law)

Comment: its quite some code, the only thing i spotted is that in `getWork` you keep a mutex for the whole duration of the function and I am not sure if this is necessary. Often making a copy is cheaper than holding a mutex for too long

Comment: You at least need the workload to be much more significant than the overhead of synchronizing and collating results across many threads.  This can probably be determined experimentally, but to be adaptable across other processors and different configurations, you could consider introducing timings that help dynamically adjust the workload size.  If you can avoid doing so much dynamic memory stuff (such as the current approach using vectors everywhere), you might improve multithreaded performance due to less synchronization with the memory allocator.  Or use thread-local allocation.

Comment: @paddy i agree with the first part, that's why i'm in trouble parallelizing a program that has so few work to do. For the dynamic memory problem, with what could i substitue the vectors?

Comment: @idclev463035818 so i sould put the mutex, make a copy, work on it, and when i finish i should put back in the queue the results and delete the data that i started from?

Comment: To me, it looks like there could be a theoretical maximum number of choices for any move.  Or at least some kind of realistic value.  So perhaps you can be smarter about using pre-allocated memory.  Especially if the size of a "choice" is condensed.  Currently it's 81 bytes, but it could be 4 bits per cell (41 bytes) or even 10^81 which fits in 34 bytes.  You should really be profiling/instrumenting your program to find out where it is spending the most time.

Comment: Note my above comments assume a "choice" represents an entire board position, when in fact a choice from some initial board position might only need to store the cell 0-80 and a value 1-9.  This information easily fits into two bytes.

Comment: @paddy i profiled it with valgrind and i fixed all the dynamic memory allocation (before it has 70kb in average while now just 4kb). So now is much faster, and the profiling tells me that the most time spending (like 90%) is in the computation of each nodes, that is sequential code. But i still got the problem: 8000 computations sequentially -> time = 0.05, the same 8000 computations with 2 threads(so theoretycally 4'000 each) -> time = 0.05...

Comment: @GiovanniSan Is it a hard requirement for the assignment for your multithreaded version to run faster? Because just the cost of starting up the threads could take longer than the singlethreaded version. In fact, it's already so fast that it's hard to even show how the time is spent. If you want to increase the workload while sticking with sudoku, you could pick a larger board size. "Generic sudoku" is NP-Hard, so you can scale up the problem until runtime is significant.