# Can't benefit from multithreading and don't know why

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization

i have a c++ program to parallelize, i profiled the program with valgrind to see which is the "heavy part" where most of the time is spent, and i parallelized it. However even using multiple threads i still have no benefits and can't understand why. The program is a sudoku brute force solver, where starting from the root node, i keep iterating pushing in a queue each possible solution. The queue plays the role of a task pool, so then i fetch again from it, compute the node and each possible number that would fit, and pushing them back again. The program keeps iterating like that until a solution is met. So the heavy work is clearly computing each node. I parallelized it creating more threads that do the same work: they fetch from the queue, iterate, and pushing back results until a solution is met. i think that the only overhead from having multiple threads is the synchronization of the fetching, and pushing back results, with the queue, because i just create the threads and the beginning and keep looping using busy waiting if needed, so i don't think the thread creation impact so much. I have profiled the version using just 1 thread and the one using 2 threads for exaple but i can't figure out what is the problem of no benefits.

The questions are:

1. how can i see (with valgrind if needed) how much is the "cost"(so the time that i waste) for synchronize each thread with the queue?
   2)Most important, what could be the cause of having no benefits in using multiple threads?

P.S. i also put a counter in the code to see how many computations the program does before reaching the result, and when the sequential versione does for exaple 8'000 computations, and the 2-thread version does 8'000 computations too(so more or less 4'000 each thread) the time is more or less the same...so literally no advantages...why?

I will post the most important parts of the code and the two (1-thread and 2-thread verisons) of the valgrind reports.

REPORT: Sequential version
[image: REPORT: Sequential version]

REPORT: 2-Thread version
[image]

And the most important parts of the code here:

```
//Each node has a sudoku grid and some sub-trees
struct Node {
    array<unsigned  char, N*N> grid;
    //vector<Node *> child;
    Node * child[9] = {nullptr};
};


Node *newNode(const array<unsigned  char, N*N> &newGrid) {
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->grid = newGrid;
    return temp;
}

//This is the task pool queue
list<vector<Node *>> queueWork(0, vector<Node *>(0));


//Find all possible numbers that can be inserted, and update the grid with that solution. Return the set of all
//the grids, one for each possible choice.
vector<array<unsigned char, N*N>> getChoices(const int &row, const int &col, const array<unsigned  char, N*N> &grid) {
    vector<array<unsigned char, N*N>> choices;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (canInsert(i, row, col, grid)) {
            array<unsigned char, N*N> tmpGrid = grid;
            tmpGrid[row+col*N] = i;
            choices.push_back(move(tmpGrid));
        }
    }
    return choices;
}

//Get a work from the queue
vector<Node *> getWork(const int chunkSize) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lck(mtx);
    
    if(queueWork.empty()){
        vector<Node *> error;
        return error;
    }
    auto tmp = queueWork.back();
    queueWork.pop_back();
    return tmp;
}

//Put a work in the queue
void pushWork(vector<Node *> &work) {
    lock_guard<mutex> lck(mtx);
    queueWork.push_back(work);
    return;
}

void solveSudoku(vector<Node *> &nodes) {
    for (Node *&n : nodes) {
        if (findCell(n->grid) != ERROR_PAIR) {
            pair<int, int> freeCell = findCell(n->grid);
            vector<array<unsigned char, N*N>> choices = getChoices(freeCell.first, freeCell.second, n->grid);
            if (choices.empty()) { 
                delete n;
                continue; 
                }
            addChoices(choices, *n);
            vector<Node *> result;
            for (auto &n : n->child) {
                
                if(n!=nullptr) result.push_back(n);
            }
            pushWork(result);  //I Push back in the queue the children.
            delete n;
            continue;
        } else if (isSolution(n->grid) && !solutionFound) {
                solutionFound.store(true);
                printGrid(n->grid);
                cout << "That's the first solution found !" << endl;
                return;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
   }
}

void infiniteLoop(const int chunkSize){
    while(!solutionFound){
        if(!queueWork.empty()){
            auto part = getWork(chunkSize);
            if(!part.empty()) {
                solveSudoku(part);
            }
        }
    } 
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    array<unsigned char, N*N> grid = {0}; 

    if(seed != 0 && initialValues != 0){ 
        generateMatrix(seed,initialValues,grid);
    } else {
        grid = 
                                      {9, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 
                                       0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 
                                       0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       5, 0, 2, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 0, 
                                       0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 
                                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                       0, 0, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7};
    }
    
//I do the first iteration manually to fill a bit the task pool queue.
    Node *root = newNode(grid);
    vector<Node *> primoLavoro ;
    primoLavoro.push_back(root);
    solveSudoku(primoLavoro);

    vector<thread> tids;

        for(int i=0;i<nw;i++){
            tids.push_back(thread(infiniteLoop,chunkSize));
        }

        for(thread &t : tids){
            t.join();
        }
    
   if(!solutionFound) cout << "No solution found ! " << endl;
   return(0);
    
}
```

Comment: Look into "work stealing" to reduce contention on the shared work queue. Each thread can pull a task into its own work queue and spawn new tasks there. If a thread is out of work it can steal work from other threads.

Comment: how long does the sequential version take, how long does the parallel version take? If I read the screenshots correctly (italian?) then `getChoices` takes 10% so even if you can make this twice as fast the total runtime with 2 threads will be 95% of the sequential one. Read about Amdahls law if you didnt do it already

Comment: @idclev463035818 getChoices yes, but infiniteLoop(that is the function threads runs) takes 92% of the total program time

Comment: Dynamic memory management, in particular that hidden in things like `std::vector`, is a "popular" barrier to parallelism.

Comment: I think you need to have a per thread work queue to avoid all the time spent in the mutex.

Comment: @molbdnilo and what is the "popular" solution then? I mean, i can't know at compile time how much memory i will need, i can't even set an upper bound..what could i do

Comment: you posted similar code before and again the first thing I spot is that for each iteration of the infinite loop you hold a mutex for the whole duration of `getWork`. I'd expect an improvement if you can remove the mutex, perhaps get the work for several iterations at once. At least you could reduce the duration each thread keeps the mutex locked. Every time you lock a mutex this incurs overhead. If you do this in every iteration it is expensive

Comment: @idclev463035818 about "getWork", in the sequential version is costs 21.75% of the total time, while in the 2-thread version it costs 21.74% of the total time, so it will improve both versions ok, but i need first to understand why the multithreaded isn't ok

Comment: Maybe your memory performance is the limiting factor.

Comment: @drescherjm sorry can you exaplain a little bit more what u mean? (sorry)

Comment: It may be that the limiting factor of your performance is not the CPU but is the RAM subsystem or even as @molbdnilo mentioned dynamic allocation. With that said why are you only testing 2 threads? Perhaps 4 or 8 threads will tell you something else.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: From your [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519121/how-to-parallelize-a-program-that-need-0-005-seconds-to-terminate-sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63519121/how-to-parallelize-a-program-that-need-0-005-seconds-to-terminate-sequentially) question I think that multithreading will not solve this problem. There is a time cost for creating additional threads that you are likely fighting against.

Comment: All these functions are sequential: 21.74% of time in getWork, 7.77% in pushWork, 12.34% in new, 19.93% in delete. You're doing extra copies all over the place (ex: `std::move` an array does a copy, not a move. ex: getWork/pushWork copy the vector). You don't show the values for N and chunkSize. Is `solutionFound` an atomic variable? If not, the other thread might be missing the early-out. Try to do all the memory allocation up front or avoid `std::vector` which may be doing allocation.

Comment: Representing Sudoku grid and solving it can be done elegantly with no heap allocations. This code is heap allocation bonanza and that's another reason it doesn't scale, in addition to locking the mutex for too long.

Comment: A single-threaded C++ solver with no heap allocation brute forces your puzzle in 2481 steps in 33 microseconds. Throwing more threads at the problem may well result in longer run-time due to threading overheads being larger than the amount of CPU cycles required to solve it. The most difficult puzzle I have come across so far is brute-forced in 392926 steps in 4 milliseconds.

Comment: [An incredible solver in C++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191041/90247): ~49k puzzles in 0.2 second. Roughly 3220x faster than my naive brute-forcer. Time to pack and go home.

Comment: That list of ~49k puzzles has some good problems, the worst one for my naive C++ brute-forcer takes 22e9 steps to solve, 1.7 seconds.